# How to fix collision for objects beyond their green lines?

Tags: unity, collision-detection, sprites, tilemap

As you can see in the image those are collision lines but its kinda of disingenuous as there are I would say invisible collision blocks on the X's, I tried messing around with the sorting layers and what not but to no avail. Is there are method to get smooth collision where my character can touch the object with its sprite without walking through it?

[image]

Comment: How have you set up your character, and how do you move them?